# How to build components dynamically according to data from API?

Tags: javascript, angular

**Functionality description**:

User can add tabs (like browser tabs). In each tab there is a list of charts, which can be choosed by user. This setup is saved on account (backend) and will be always shown for this user.

**Example**

User1 has 2 tabs: tab1 - 3 charts, tab2 - other 2 charts

User2 has 1 tab: tab1 - 1 chart

**My question**

What is the best way to implement this on Angular? I'm looking for the best practice. Which format should I send data of the setup to backend. How to render components based on data come from backend?

Comment: This depends on how APIs are structured. How many APIs do you have? is every info will come in single API or you have seperate API for tabs and charts?

Comment: Info for charts is coming from one API, but info for stucture of tabs and charts from another